# php base64_decode part corrupt using xampp on windows 7

Tags: php, xampp, base64

I have a problem with some third party php scripts not decoding properly using xampp on windows 7. The process is that the script sends an encrypted payload to an external server where it is decrypted and returned. We have no access or control of the external server. The relevant code is:

```
$response = $provider->request('package/decode/' . $endpoint, 'POST', $params);
$data = $response->toXml();
if (isset($data->object)) {
  $object = (string)$data->object;
  $object = base64_decode($object);
  $object = unserialize($object);
}
if (isset($data->related_objects)) {
  $relatedObjects = (string)$data->related_objects;
  $relatedObjects = base64_decode($relatedObjects);
  $relatedObjects = unserialize($relatedObjects);
}
```

The `$object` decodes with no problem. The `$relatedObjects` does not and looks corrupt part way through:

`YToxOntzOjEyOiJQbHVnaW5FdmVudHMiO2E6MTA6e3M6MzI6ImQ0NzM2NzJjM2YyNzk2NjVhYTNmNWJlNjBjMzU2MjYyIjthOjg6e3M6MTM6InByZXNlcnZlX2tleXMiO2I6MTtzOjEzOiJ1cGRhdGVfb2JqZWN0IjtiOjA7czoxMDoidW5pcXVlX2tleSI7YToyOntpOjA7czo4OiJwbHVnaW5pZCI7aToxO3M6NToiZXZlbnQiO31zOjU6ImNsYXNzIjtzOjE0OiJtb2RQbHVnaW5FdmVudCI7czo2OiJvYmplY3QiO3M6NzU6InsicGx1Z2luaWQiOjAsImV2ZW50IjoiT25SaWNoVGV4dEJyb3dzZXJJbml0IiwicHJpb3JpdHkiOjAsInByb3BlcnR5c2V0IjowfSI7czo0OiJndWlkIjtzOjMyOiIwMDMzMTExNjBkMDkwYzUxY2FjN2E5Mzg4ZDQzMDNiNyI7czoxMDoibmF0aXZlX2tleSI7YToyOntpOjA7aTowO2k6MTtzOjIxOiJPblJpY2hUZXh0QnJvd3NlckluaXQiO31zOjk6InNpZ25hdHVyZSI7czozMjoiZDVhYjlmMTVjOWY3ODNkZTJhNDFiMzZjMTlkMTUwNGQiO31zOjMyOiI3YzczZTg3OGI5MzZiOTRmMGQzZmVhNjJhNzIzMGM0MyI7YTo4OntzOjEzOiJwcmVzZXJ2ZV9rZXlzIjtiOjE7czoxMzoidXBkYXRlX29iamVjdCI7YjowO3M6MTA6InVuaXF1ZV9rZXkiO2E6Mjp7aTowO3M6ODoicGx1Z2luaWQiO2k6MTtzOjU6ImV2ZW50Ijt9czo1OiJjbGFzcyI7czoxNDoibW9kUGx1Z2luRXZlbnQiO3M6Njoib2JqZWN0IjtzOjc5OiJ7InBsdWdpbmlkIjowLCJldmVudCI6Ik9uTWFuYWdlclBhZ2VCZWZvcmVSZW5kZXIiLCJwcmlvcml0eSI6MCwicHJvcGVydHlzZXQiOjB9IjtzOjQ6Imd1aWQiO3M6MzI6IjZkMTdjMDRhZTkyNjQ4ZTUzNTk0MjViODI5NWUzOWQ1IjtzOjEwOiJuYXRpdmVfa2V5IjthOjI6e2k6MDtpOjA7aToxO3M6MjU6Ik9uTWFuYWdlclBhZ2VCZWZvcmVSZW5kZXIiO31zOjk6InNpZ25hdHVyZSI7czozMjoiZDYyYzc1NGM3OTEzYzhlNTE3NWNkMzVhNTJmMWUzMGQiO31zOjMyOiI2ZTUxNGI1MTYwNGNmMzdmODQ2ZTY3N2U5YzVhYzA5MCI7YTo4OntzOjEzOiJwcmVzZXJ2ZV9rZXlzIjtiOjE7czoxMzoidXBkYXRlX29iamVjdCI7YjowO3M6MTA6InVuaXF1ZV9rZXkiO2E6Mjp7aTowO3M6ODoicGx1Z2luaWQiO2k6MTtzOjU6ImV2ZW50Ijt9czo1OiJjbGFzcyI7czoxNDoibW9kUGx1Z2luRXZlbnQiO3M6Njoib2JqZWN0IjtzOjcyOiJ7InBsdWdpbmlkIjowLCJldmVudCI6Ik9uRG9jRm9ybVByZXJlbmRlciIsInByaW9yaXR5IjowLCJwcm9wZXJ0eXNldCI6MH0iO3M6NDoiZ3VpZCI7czozMjoiZTY0MGZjM2Y5NDUyNzQ5MWRkZjc1NzM3ZTEwMDI2NjAiO3M6MTA6Im5hdGl2ZV9rZXkiO2E6Mjp7aTowO2k6MDtpOjE7czoxODoiT25Eb2NGb3JtUHJlcmVuZGVyIjt9czo5OiJzaWduYXR1cmUiO3M6MzI6IjljNjBhY2FiODQ0OGI4ZTEzMDI4MDE1Njg1MzE1YzZiIjt9czozMjoiMDg2ZWUyMjUxODljMmVmN2Y2ODBiZDVhZTY0YjQ5NjQiO2E6ODp7czoxMzoicHJlc2VydmVfa2V5cyI7YjoxO3M6MTM6InVwZGF0ZV9vYmplY3QiO2I6MDtzOjEwOiJ1bmlxdWVfa2V5IjthOjI6e2k6MDtzOjg6InBsdWdpbmlkIjtpOjE7czo1OiJldmVudCI7fXM6NToiY2xhc3MiO3M6MTQ6Im1vZFBsdWdpbkV2ZW50IjtzOjY6Im9iamVjdCI7czo3ODoieyJwbHVnaW5pZCI6MCwiZXZlbnQiOiJPblJpY2hUZXh0RWRpdG9yUmVnaXN0ZXIiLCJwcmlvcml0eSI6MCwicHJvcGVydHlzZXQiOjB9IjtzOjQ6Imd1aWQiO3M6MzI6ImM0NWQ1OGU5ZmVkNWQ5NDcyZTlmMDExMDU2YjNhMDg3IjtzOjEwOiJuYXRpdmVfa2V5IjthOjI6e2k6MDtpOjA7aToxO3M6MjQ6Ik9uUmljaFRleHRFZGl0b3JSZWdpc3RlciI7fXM6OToic2lnbmF0dXJlIjtzOjMyOiIxMWJlZDhiOGYyZWQxOWEyZTVkZmEwYWY2MjU1NDJmOSI7fXM6MzI6ImIyOGFkZTdjNDQ4ZmRjMmJkMzdlZTBlNGQ0ODEyMTE1IjthOjg6e3M6MTM6InByZXNlcnZlX2tleXMiO2I6MTtzOjEzOiJ1cGRhdGVfb2JqZWN0IjtiOjA7czoxMDoidW5pcXVlX2tleSI7YToyOntpOjA7czo4OiJwbHVnaW5pZCI7aToxO3M6NToiZXZlbnQiO31zOjU6ImNsYXNzIjtzOjE0OiJtb2RQbHVnaW5FdmVudCI7czo2OiJvYmplY3QiO3M6NzM6InsicGx1Z2luaWQiOjAsImV2ZW50IjoiT25UVklucHV0UmVuZGVyTGlzdCIsInByaW9yaXR5IjowLCJwcm9wZXJ0eXNldCI6MH0iO3M6NDoiZ3VpZCI7czozMjoiZjg1MWU0OTdmZDg5ZDBiY2Y4MDRmNGVmZDRmOTVlMmMiO3M6MTA6Im5hdGl2ZV9rZXkiO2E6Mjp7aTowO2k6MDtpOjE7czoxOToiT25UVklucHV0UmVuZGVyTGlzdCI7fXM6OToic2lnbmF0dXJlIjtzOjMyOiJjN2M5YTA4MWUyY2E4ZTI4ZGU2OTViMmUwYzM3MzhhMCI7fXM6MzI6IjIwOTFkOGFlMjQ3ZmY0NzQwMjI3NmU4NGUwNDY3ZDMwIjthOjg6e3M6MTM6InByZXNlcnZlX2tleXMiO2I6MTtzOjEzOiJ1cGRhdGVfb2JqZWN0IjtiOjA7czoxMDoidW5pcXVlX2tleSI7YToyOntpOjA7czo4OiJwbHVnaW5pZCI7aToxO3M6NToiZXZlbnQiO31zOjU6ImNsYXNzIjtzOjE0OiJtb2RQbHVnaW5FdmVudCI7czo2OiJvYmplY3QiO3M6NzQ6InsicGx1Z2luaWQiOjAsImV2ZW50IjoiT25UVk91dHB1dGUG2ApmKwV9XbLEl8hy9QJ6yTZ2NnvVRfTjhvx3hq3ZXLDI21gcc0/UMBXxXTkbVOlOtapxOTH1eK3xIXwKkPy38Y5zLjHFaNyK5cPoQpP5FbP1qjUNUrgrbQGKeEfRGsIAbtzHT2qTxzgY7z/epePkvclKqWa194ZevVGKQN0z0jLLZ2REY/ZSadUQVP/LcIew8P//MvY/8YeFF5mxyutlTdRJ9oMwRZ5pMI2wT/mmsx2aeeVh1WcFP7/OqEzhHT8XIUwV96DYv/aFmetP6avi1ygnWTVZpnuXWmoSorfgwnAUzU76j3iv4f0szvn8BG6IvvXxMOuTCazD6H0lteI4KKSW6VAIj205AxFOuEqUp9iHcb4O2e/vkDW8Rn0ayfVIOagnMcU1oshb41KNZezuJBdv99IpbKOKnSy3SnPf+RzdkLWuFWek7I51O9xYzxdMiwot0alVPjZcepC2k9NAH/oQ0Uj2ks0djW6lwDXfYUAJkzem3qTwUj0eEac/fIKZAd84GBy3Bgef+migngUrnqRWyTqpJ8S0Jt61XzQogNrSrB8ZuqT+vbrkaLDBtTI49MmvlMcN0bf2PAhkoaMSwISL3d4iv4FRPaNUhtHe3XyWomnZwjckCOUEHdPC7ptUBkYGlatqNw259eQi2QubaCR87JX8FPUo1U5pQiVqK74QHBc8gVTfoybY2cMtMZ3qmzBymsn6ugeeGEoW6C+0nAqqhJOp7ZNJ4Y30rnMyjrcqX1L1dGClu1HMAhZ1HR7iYMlB2EDSlkxMzrBWdeUqXon0yuKltLLr9BlFtY0in/6NKRy6CQnIdsQvp0ZhBiHVUsdPNmTX7OI/arvkvKT7Pw8UcRkraDJgCJm+GQ5lLi7E22diyxwtPCYaR0936XIGWqzcJFUGSaWApH3y8q8c8+3FOlmpdxali1mDfO4zQT05D+B7EADFxnPoXdXaUSd/enArOOJO8NFqMTwgJ2Z2ujaBLpkojPE4aJLdzihqEvPA3gd8dwZBw5vsSDDpajiz9/vCh7YgDJwotKCXw41qRWDD6hKeyfkosVEqUOMZn0nxG9RHVdrKdH2KJquaLdndgTzOOCnPcU753TcG6sjVnSokexmx2/KA2P5+wjNe8G8cO61OhfuXGFLE7LslNc+urnVeLYAsN+SnBZYeFF+XooXK1JiZtIUo3JHKi037T1qevfvy6EcHaALwGBUPmR7J9H+YckekfEaMK4TC6dCb5fwNaDKSpYk9GNj5mVzQ676PzvWffcS8o2ZdqFryUM0GNr0sSVRhlo7rYjjPGUOu1hIhrBNGEcOePBRutK3V8HstKmTDdyIB6dGtS3D+8MhZOz6DBu8DlNerqsYXxKA7qlQ5cfVrM+CpO4yUobiqQfCQaTkXMp2352ORppa+9VG0tVa74eZnyHQgugz8d4XRxBo4VA5vMOCA3yg34+q2/CayXEPE6VAlIhf1agZ3vfRBxVZEUSWR0SV1ut5Y9crHkBoEjF9m/NEO/Os7mD69tSsJelsO3gfhuzZX8FgZSpOX3mwrdjoS0h/w3s1BKkg6srOZ9zbFx/34xTZBIwYBwfV4i3GzSZiFY0NiqT/3hXkaWZqzv4IuT4J9AZOUFjZxpdkdDbCo3nXEhDcg/DdISg1WbPuFjOHed50GD2el/Y+cS3cKrbwzVWom/Jt8dwTSPfU+j+w5IpEDOC85VYl+G4nqs9pxnbNw9eB9yPCUrCg9p5EJzwdOrvXX6DmkmLZ9+1I3+9T0TUQ9vsi10CnCdIF2tjdWR+vbxJkBDfIL9Ji0dfw4TtSZm+NtqER4GvbhcIq9sA1Lnf7Sy8jbd/ifhR0804bCvcvRTCa+zHDwauGYyV9jXd4fKLI7CAai8ot29x1hTypyzDcGCU0xKZgHAHRSxHd2tiEYUmvUJzhg7prdXwgdSEexe/hLRAHVNxo3G7JPV/D86YUdex8Ya+lbnwF1+V7k2Yz7uUehLkt6r1LpbMCdFwFvXvhQkd8QWoM3qlFNtkV0KeyI99nOPOAQqRJ5tlqmKNYHgVGs29y1DGltSQP5dN4LTbOFKsHl0kSKQFEqTqguU+qP8sLe/ID3Vvn1HslwqqWIvq5PLpjJtoS39lMQdWhxAuZNSccFP/2Rdrzx9IWuRbIQuRTa48Gtf3RJBZysslo6DrfYnEdvReE1aGMXV/tEiOFYyZsrKgSzvpaVVmN7uQRwPqOsNakBPjdz4ibEN0ZYpuoYDlJos/VxhlNi/KLbFosufeEXbqDx5eSWYl6BNRgnB2+qX/AO+hNuanN4Y711Sx8AJReInSUlgCG1QPrej7ZAYp+v1j1+i3oQw45Qtm2gBmFmWlMU4moDXZHwYNK0+OUfggZ8IESROYL85bQft+IvQMqGodgdEFY0ztWB3EItOVW6wS21HpMJ8CKJdqGFRSPuq9qoewjqRFkduG/Vnn1xib1tWz3OpILecoCCLehiaFN+rWX5ZN7cw3acJRq29oILLaw/I7teu119ASNo3J2OjJ1Ct6QYJB0FSa5Jsr4EhnZaf0r6VI7MM7aOAe1XMOXP0F2ks1Ash057XMxLdkdB8EKGQPm4w0aYxRbRoY4UK8nxERZHyxb4XpxIfN1mHXMV2TalbyyxB3dMLK80csIPzRRPdpvUnFRNynw1ZaJUrypTZfWBnf2eNbT6ynWrWmrBR5+jKuOwevGidfh5tE6U4prLU8as+/ARq/E4TfVfjUesfDSbyRqd/FDxpHeI3pVTwW4gsA==`

Result:

`a:1:{s:12:"PluginEvents";a:10:{s:32:"d473672c3f279665aa3f5be60c356262";a:8:{s:13:"preserve_keys";b:1;s:13:"update_object";b:0;s:10:"unique_key";a:2:{i:0;s:8:"pluginid";i:1;s:5:"event";}s:5:"class";s:14:"modPluginEvent";s:6:"object";s:75:"{"pluginid":0,"event":"OnRichTextBrowserInit","priority":0,"propertyset":0}";s:4:"guid";s:32:"003311160d090c51cac7a9388d4303b7";s:10:"native_key";a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:1;s:21:"OnRichTextBrowserInit";}s:9:"signature";s:32:"d5ab9f15c9f783de2a41b36c19d1504d";}s:32:"7c73e878b936b94f0d3fea62a7230c43";a:8:{s:13:"preserve_keys";b:1;s:13:"update_object";b:0;s:10:"unique_key";a:2:{i:0;s:8:"pluginid";i:1;s:5:"event";}s:5:"class";s:14:"modPluginEvent";s:6:"object";s:79:"{"pluginid":0,"event":"OnManagerPageBeforeRender","priority":0,"propertyset":0}";s:4:"guid";s:32:"6d17c04ae92648e5359425b8295e39d5";s:10:"native_key";a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:1;s:25:"OnManagerPageBeforeRender";}s:9:"signature";s:32:"d62c754c7913c8e5175cd35a52f1e30d";}s:32:"6e514b51604cf37f846e677e9c5ac090";a:8:{s:13:"preserve_keys";b:1;s:13:"update_object";b:0;s:10:"unique_key";a:2:{i:0;s:8:"pluginid";i:1;s:5:"event";}s:5:"class";s:14:"modPluginEvent";s:6:"object";s:72:"{"pluginid":0,"event":"OnDocFormPrerender","priority":0,"propertyset":0}";s:4:"guid";s:32:"e640fc3f94527491ddf75737e1002660";s:10:"native_key";a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:1;s:18:"OnDocFormPrerender";}s:9:"signature";s:32:"9c60acab8448b8e13028015685315c6b";}s:32:"086ee225189c2ef7f680bd5ae64b4964";a:8:{s:13:"preserve_keys";b:1;s:13:"update_object";b:0;s:10:"unique_key";a:2:{i:0;s:8:"pluginid";i:1;s:5:"event";}s:5:"class";s:14:"modPluginEvent";s:6:"object";s:78:"{"pluginid":0,"event":"OnRichTextEditorRegister","priority":0,"propertyset":0}";s:4:"guid";s:32:"c45d58e9fed5d9472e9f011056b3a087";s:10:"native_key";a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:1;s:24:"OnRichTextEditorRegister";}s:9:"signature";s:32:"11bed8b8f2ed19a2e5dfa0af625542f9";}s:32:"b28ade7c448fdc2bd37ee0e4d4812115";a:8:{s:13:"preserve_keys";b:1;s:13:"update_object";b:0;s:10:"unique_key";a:2:{i:0;s:8:"pluginid";i:1;s:5:"event";}s:5:"class";s:14:"modPluginEvent";s:6:"object";s:73:"{"pluginid":0,"event":"OnTVInputRenderList","priority":0,"propertyset":0}";s:4:"guid";s:32:"f851e497fd89d0bcf804f4efd4f95e2c";s:10:"native_key";a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:1;s:19:"OnTVInputRenderList";}s:9:"signature";s:32:"c7c9a081e2ca8e28de695b2e0c3738a0";}s:32:"2091d8ae247ff47402276e84e0467d30";a:8:{s:13:"preserve_keys";b:1;s:13:"update_object";b:0;s:10:"unique_key";a:2:{i:0;s:8:"pluginid";i:1;s:5:"event";}s:5:"class";s:14:"modPluginEvent";s:6:"object";s:74:"{"pluginid":0,"event":"OnTVOutputeØ
f+}]²ÄÈrõzÉ6v6{ÕEôãüw­Ù\°ÈÛXsOÔ0ñ]9TéNµªq91õx­ñ!|
ü·ñs.1ÅhÜåÃèBù³õª5
R¸+mxGÑÂnÜÇOjÇ8ï?Þ¥ãä½ÉJ©fµ÷^½Q@Ý3Ò2ËgdDcöRiÕTÿËp°ðÿÿ2ö?ñ±ÊëeMÔIö0Ei0°Où¦³yåaÕg?¿Î¨Lá?!L÷ Ø¿öëOé«â×('Y5Y¦{Zj¢·àÂpÍNúx¯áý,Îùün¾õñ0ë    ¬Ãè}%µâ8(¤éPm9N¸J§Øq¾Ùïï5¼F}ÉõH9¨'1Å5¢È[ãReìî$o÷Ò)l£,·JsßùÝµ®g¤ìu;ÜXÏL
-Ñ©U>6\z¶Ó@úÑHöÍn¥À5ßa@  7¦Þ¤ðR=§?|ß8·úh +¤VÉ:©'Ä´&Þµ_4(ÚÒ¬º¤þ½ºäh°Áµ28ôÉ¯Ç
Ñ·ö<d¡£ÀÝÞ"¿Q=£TÑÞÝ|¢iÙÂ7$åÓÂîTF«j7
¹õä"Ùh$|ìüõ(ÕNiB%j+¾<Tß£&ØÙÃ-1ê0rÉúºJè/´
ª©íIáô®s2·*_Rõt`¥»QÌuâ`ÉAØ@ÒLLÎ°Vuå*^ôÊâ¥´²ëôEµ"þ)º     ÈvÄ/§Fa!ÕRÇO6d×ìâ?j»ä¼¤û?q+h2`¾e..ÄÛgbË-<&GOwérZ¬Ü$UI¥¤}òò¯óíÅ:Y©w¥Y|î3A=9à{ÅÆsè]ÕÚQ'zp+8âNðÑj1< 'fvº6.(ñ8hÝÎ(jóÀÞ|wAÃìH0éj8³÷ûÂ¶ (´ ÃjE`ÃêÉù(±Q*PãIñÔGUÚÊt}&«-ÙÝ<Î8)ÏqNùÝ7êÈÕ*${±ÛòØþ~Â3^ðo;­NûRÄì»%5Ï®®u^-,7ä§_¢ÊÔ´(ÜÊMûOZ½ûòèGhðÉôrG¤|F+ÂéÐåü
h2¥=Øù\Ðë¾Îõ}Ä¼£f]¨ZòPÍ6½,ITaëb8ÏC®Ö!¬FÃ<n´­Õð{-*dÃw"éÑ­KpþðÈY;>ï×«ªÆÄ ;ªT9qõk3à©;¡¸ªAði92·çc¦¾õQ´µV»áægÈt ºüwÑÄ8To0àß(7ãê¶ü&²\CÄéP%"õjw½ôAÅVDQ%Ñ%uºÞXõÊÇ_füÑüë;>½µ+    z[Þá»6WðXJÞl+v:ÒðÞÍA*H:²³÷6ÅÇýøÅ6A#Áõxq³IcCb©?÷yY³¿.O}6q¥Ù
°¨ÞuÄ7 ü7HJ
VlûáÞwg¥ýKw
­¼3Uj&ü|wÒ=õ>ì9"8/9U~ê³Úq³põà}Èð¬(=§ ÏN®õ×è9¤¶}ûR7ûÔôMD=¾ÈµÐ)Âtv¶7VGëÛÄ
òô´uü8NÔãm¨Dxöáp½°
KþÒËÈÛwø<ÓÂ½ËÑL&¾ÌpðjáÉ_c]Þ(²;¢òv÷aO*rÌ7    M1)tRÄwv¶!RkÔ'8`îÝ_HG±{øKDÕ77²OWðüé{ké[uù^äÙû¹G¡.Kz¯RélÀo^øPßZ7ªQM¶Et)ì÷ÙÎ<à©y¶Z¦(ÖQ¬ÛÜµimIùtÞM³*ÁåÒD@Q*N¨.SêòÂÞü÷VùõÉpª¥¾®O.É¶·öSuhqæMIÇ?ýv¼ñô®E²¹ÚãÁ­tI¬²Z:·ØGoEá5hcWûDáXÉ+*³¾Vc{¹p>£¬5©>7sâ&Ä7FX¦êRh³õqSbü¢Û.}án ñåäb^5'oª_ðúnjsxc½uK%%%!µ@úÞ¶@b¯Ö=~zÃP¶m afZSâj]ð`Ò´øå| D9üå´·â/@Ê¡ØV4ÎÕÜB-9UºÁ-µ    ð"v¡E#î«Ú¨{êDY¸oÕ}q½m[=Î¤Þr-èbhS~­eùdÞÜÃv%¶ö-¬?#»^»]}#hÜB·¤$I®I²¾vZJúTÌ3¶íW0åÏÐ]¤³P,N{\ÌKvGAðB@ù¸ÃFÅÑ¡+ÉñGËø^H|ÝfsÙ6¥o,±wL,¯4rÂÍOvÔTMÊ|5e¢T¯*Seõý5´úÊu«ZjÁG£*ã°zñ¢uøy´NâËSÆ¬ûð«ñ8Mõ_G¬|4ÉüPñ¤wÞSÁn °`

There are no php errors or errors at the software providers end either. I have set Apache and PHPs charsets to UTF-8. I have the same script working on an external centos 7 setup and the vendor says other customers use xampp with no problem. So I'm guessing this is a local character encoding problem with windows or php? How can I to narrow it down so I can decode the string correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess was that a piece of the data is missing, and because of the cyclic inner structure of base64 if we'd cut off at a different offset we could get the data back.

So I've tried:

```
echo base64_decode(substr($payload, $offset));
```

for different offsets around 3400 (where the corruption starts), and got no luck! At any offset it was still gibberish.

Then I tried collecting byte statistics to see if it's coherent to the distribution usually found in text files to which JSON belongs.

```
$pivot = 3400;
$decodeJson = base64_decode(substr($payload, 0, $pivot));
$decodeGibberish = base64_decode(substr($payload, $pivot));

print_r(getByteDistribution($decodeJson));
print str_repeat('-', 100) . "\n";
print_r(getByteDistribution($decodeGibberish));

function getByteDistribution(string $input): array {
    $distribution = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); ++$i) {
        $ord = ord($input[$i]);
        if (!isset($distribution[$ord])) {
            $distribution[$ord] = 0;
        }
        $distribution[$ord]++;
    }
    arsort($distribution, SORT_NUMERIC);
    return $distribution;
}
```

And this is what I got:

```
Array
(
    [58] => 281
    [34] => 236
    [101] => 181
    [115] => 132
    [59] => 129
    [105] => 101
    [48] => 88
    [49] => 83
    [116] => 76
    [110] => 76
    [97] => 70
    [100] => 69
    [50] => 66
    [114] => 61
    [51] => 60
    [99] => 55
    [53] => 52
    [52] => 50
    [117] => 49
    [56] => 47
    ...skipped for brevity...
)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Array
(
    [245] => 21
    [222] => 19
    [240] => 18
    [6] => 18
    [252] => 17
    [55] => 16
    [106] => 15
    [201] => 15
    [79] => 14
    [133] => 14
    [56] => 14
    [119] => 14
    [29] => 14
    [117] => 14
    [164] => 13
    [118] => 13
    [157] => 13
    [104] => 13
    [196] => 13
    [241] => 13
    ...skipped for brevity...
)
```

I advise you to run it and see for yourself: while distribution in JSON part shows high peaks for often-repeated character, the distribution for gibberish is much more even.

Which is a strong indicator for encrypted data.

So the problem is not with the payload, but with deciphering it.

And it occurred to me that there is just the same common problem when uploading a zip file to FTP. If you happen to use text mode in your FTP client, then line ending characters which may happen in the encrypted data may be irreversibly lost due to conversion. This is most often happens with Windows because it uses different line endings than Unix/Linux.

So my suggestion is that you check the code for downloading the encrypted data and see if a binary mode may be enabled somewhere. For example, if you use `fopen`, then read mode should be denoted as `'rb'` (`'b'` for binary-safe), and not just `'r'`. If you use a different transport, it's up to you to inspect it.